# Where to install python3-venv in project

Tags: python-3.x, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using a jenkins file to run the smoke tests

```
def runSmokeTest(environment) {
    docker.image("python:3.7").inside {
        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: "inhome_smoketest_authz_${environment}",
         usernameVariable: 'CLIENT_ID', passwordVariable: 'CLIENT_SECRET')]) {
            sh "make smoketest CLIENT_ID=$CLIENT_ID CLIENT_SECRET=$CLIENT_SECRET ENV=${environment}"
        }
    }
}
```

In which I am getting below error

```
make smoketest CLIENT_ID=**** CLIENT_SECRET=**** ENV=acceptance
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

    apt-get install python3-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment.

Failing command: ['/u01/app/jenkins/masters/jenkins-de-bcn-team-jenkins-master-6d64469c64-d5r87/workspace/de-inhome-smoketest/venv/bin/python3.7', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']
```

And for creating virtual env we are using Makefile as follows

```
$(VENV_BASE):
    @rm -rf venv
    @$(PYTHON_VERSION) -m venv venv
    @touch $@
```

For smoke tests we have wriiten the following code in Makefile

```
.PHONY: smoketest
smoketest: $(VENV_PROD)
    venv/bin/python src/manage.py smoke_test --client_id=$(CLIENT_ID) --client_secret=$(CLIENT_SECRET) --env=$(ENV)
```

Can you please help where I can install the python3-venv?

Comment: Sounds like you are going to need to create your image based on python:3.7 and install your libs there.

Comment: In Python 3, [`venv` is part of the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) so I'm a little surprised to see this error.  Can you edit your question to include the relevant Makefile rule?

Comment: yes we are creating venv by using make file and using that we are running smoke tests

Comment: I have added some more information, please check @David Maze

Comment: Any update guys?